# How to play around with my Android accelerometer data

Tags: android, android-sensors

Fortunately I wrote an Android application to get the accelerator data. When I am moving the device fast, I get a waving graph, like the following, so for sure I can detect how fast I'm shaking my device. How can I use the data to detect the speed of shaking? Maybe I should get the delta over each millisecond?

[image]

```
package course.examples.Sensors.ShowValues;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SensorRawAccelerometerActivity extends Activity implements
        SensorEventListener {

    private static final int UPDATE_THRESHOLD = 500;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;

    private TextView mXValueView, mYValueView, mZValueView;
    private long mLastUpdate;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mXValueView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.x_value_view);
        mYValueView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.y_value_view);
        mZValueView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.z_value_view);

        // Get reference to SensorManager
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        // Get reference to Accelerometer
        if (null == (mAccelerometer = mSensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)))
            finish();

    }

    // Register listener
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

        mLastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }

    // Unregister listener
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    // Process new reading
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

            long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (actualTime - mLastUpdate > UPDATE_THRESHOLD) {

                mLastUpdate = actualTime;

                float x = event.values[0], y = event.values[1], z = event.values[2];

                mXValueView.setText(String.valueOf(x));
                mYValueView.setText(String.valueOf(y));
                mZValueView.setText(String.valueOf(z));

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // N/A
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by the speed of shaking ?

Comment: Slope of the graph will be the speed. Steeper the slope faster you are shaking your device.

Comment: Fourier transform is your friend here. Look up a fast fourier transform library. The only issue is that you are looking for very low frequencies and that would mean a lot of sample time.

Comment: @ShivamVerma I'm assuming I am shaking/moving the device very fast.

Comment: @Eu.Dr. Yes, that is a good option. How should I efficiently apply this to the code?

Comment: @mach Seems to be a good option as well. I'm new to Android; How should I **efficiently** apply this to the code? Apache common should have good APIs for that I guess.

Comment: The Engine you are using to draw graphs should have intrinsic capabilities to find slope. Just need to explore its features. What Engine are you using?

Comment: May i know how u have created the graph of accelerometer? If you understand the plotting of the graph, then u can move further to understand the logics.

Comment: @Maven oh :) I just put a random photo to ease the explanation of what I mean!

Comment: @Eu.Dr. This graph is not the output of my program; it is a random photo just to explain things better :)